# C# datagrid (not datagridview) removed columns but still showing up when using Controls.Add(DataGrid1)

Tags: c#, dynamic, datagrid

I have code that I add a dynamic datagrid to a page.

When stepping through the code I see 4 columns in my datagrid, I use the below to remove the 2 columns I want removed, and I check the values in the datagrid and the 2 columns are gone.

When I add the datagrid to the page using:

```
PlaceholderToUse.Controls.Add(DataGrid1);
```

The datagrid still has the 2 columns displayed (even though they are removed when inspecting the datagrid element in debug mode.

I even tried setting visible to false.

Here is the code I am using:

```
int CellIndexHeaderToRemoveTitle = GetIndexByHeaderText(DataGrid1.Columns, "questiongroupingtitle");
// have to check if the index was found and if it is it wont be -1
if (CellIndexHeaderToRemoveTitle != -1)
{ 
    DataGrid1.Columns[CellIndexHeaderToRemoveTitle].Visible = false;
    DataGrid1.Columns.RemoveAt(CellIndexHeaderToRemoveTitle);
}

// look for index of column and remove it, have to do this after we remove the first one because index could chnae.
int CellIndexHeaderToRemoveCSS = GetIndexByHeaderText(DataGrid1.Columns, "questiongroupingcss");
if (CellIndexHeaderToRemoveCSS != -1)
{ 
    DataGrid1.Columns[CellIndexHeaderToRemoveCSS].Visible = false;
    DataGrid1.Columns.RemoveAt(CellIndexHeaderToRemoveCSS);
}
```

When I call it I no longer see the 2 columns I am trying to remove.  Am I doing something wrong or do I need to do something differently?

Comment: The problem is all my code is using dynamic generating everything, so I will have to work on a stand alone piece to get it to be able to be reproducible and when I do I will update, if anyone has possible solution in meantime I would appreciate it.